# PHP rewriting a json array (Undefined offset)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm taking some json, made by OpenLibrary.org, and remake a new array from the info. 
[Link to the OpenLibrary json](http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:9781599953540&jscmd=data&format=json)

here is my PHP code to decode the json:

```
$barcode = "9781599953540";

function parseInfo($barcode) {
    $url = "http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" . $barcode . "&jscmd=data&format=json";
    $contents = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json = json_decode($contents, true);
    return $json;
}
```

the new array I'm trying to make looks something like this:

```
$newJsonArray = array($barcode, $isbn13, $isbn10, $openLibrary, $title, $subTitle, $publishData, $pagination, $author0, $author1, $author2, $author3, $imageLarge, $imageMedium, $imageSmall);
```

but when I try to get the ISBN_13 to save it to $isbn13, I get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ... on line 38 
// Line 38
$isbn13 = $array[0]['identifiers']['isbn_13'];
```

And even if I try $array[1] ,[2], [3].... I get the same thing. What am I doning wrong here! O I know my Valuable names might not be the same, that's because they are in different functions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is contained in `$array`?  `var_dump($array)`.  In your code above, you populate `$json`, not `$array`.

Comment: The array is probably indexed by string keys, not integers. also, where does $array show up?

Comment: @GuyDavid Or if its origin is JSON, they may be object properties.

Comment: @Michael I know my Valuable names might not be the same, that's because they are in different functions. $json is $array.

Comment: @Throdne very well then, please `var_dump($json)` or `var_dump($array)` so we can see what's in it!

Comment: @Michael  If you want to see what the $json and $array looks like here is a link to it. http://beta.tekop.net/API/submit.php?barcode=9781599953540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is not indexed by integers, it is indexed by ISBN numbers:

```
Array
(
    // This is the first level of array key!
    [ISBN:9781599953540] => Array
        (
            [publishers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Center Street
                        )

                )

            [pagination] => 376 p.
            [subtitle] => the books of mortals
            [title] => Forbidden
            [url] => http://openlibrary.org/books/OL24997280M/Forbidden
            [identifiers] => Array
            (
                [isbn_13] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 9781599953540
                    )

                [openlibrary] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => OL24997280M
                    )
```

So, you need to call it by the first ISBN, and the key `isbn_13` is itself an array which you must access by element:

```
// Gets the first isbn_13 for this item:
$isbn13 = $array['ISBN:9781599953540']['identifiers']['isbn_13'][0];
```

Or if you need a loop over many of them:

```
foreach ($array as $isbn => $values) {
  $current_isbn13 = $values['identifiers']['isbn_13'][0];
}
```

If you expect only one each time and must be able to get its key without knowing it ahead of time but don't want a loop, you can use `array_keys()`:

```
// Get all ISBN keys:
$isbn_keys = array_keys($array);
// Pull the first one:
$your_item = $isbn_keys[0];
// And use it as your index to $array
$isbn13 = $array[$your_item]['identifiers']['isbn_13'][0];
```

If you have PHP 5.4, you can skip a step via array dereferencing!:

```
// PHP >= 5.4 only
$your_item = array_keys($array)[0];
$isbn13 = $array[$your_item]['identifiers']['isbn_13'][0];
```

Comment: I see, But the problem is anytime $barcode changes, the ['ISBN:9781599953540'] will change also. I need to make my code dynamic. Is there anyway of doing it with array_keys(). Sorry, very new to PHP. Still learning.

Comment: @Throdne do you only expect one item back each time, or many?

Comment: @Throdne see addition above for `array_keys()` usage here.